# Is anyone aware of any cognitive models that appraises interior design preferences?

Tags: measurement, experimental-psychology, aesthetics

The goal is to evaluate someone's interior design preference based on some text/image based questions. Can the personality and aesthetic profile extracted from the answers be used as inputs for a cognitive model to evaluate interior design preferences? Any related material on this topic will be appreciated.

Comment: There may be some document in this sense (interior design - psychology) however there are several major issues that make scientific psychological analysis difficult on this topic: On the one hand likes, interests, preferences and personality in this subject (I have never heard a psychological analysis about interior design) on the other hand the aesthetic criterion has always been very elusive for psychology and for science in general depending on a very high number of factors, so aesthetics has been a subject more addressed in philosophy specifically in the aesthetics of art.